# Non parametric and parametric tests of martingale?

Tags: econometrics, time-series

A martingale is a model in which the expectation for the next value is equal to the presently observed value, even given knowledge of prior values, *ie*

$E(X_{n+1} |X_1, X_2, ..,X_n)=X_n$

What tests for testing if a time series is a martingale are available? I am particularly interested in non-parametric tests. Is there any relation with conditional moments literature?

Comment: I would suggest you to read Escanciano and Lobato (2003) "Testing the Martingale Hypothesis" (it was reprinted in the Palgrave Handbook of Econometrics too).  Here's a link to it:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9780230244405_20